# How Can send a List<> to Rest web api server From Xamarin forms

Tags: list, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a List that I want to send to the server and my code is as follows but it's wrong and I don't know how to send the list!

```cs
public async Task<TEntity> GetByAdsIdList<TEntity>(string dbTableName, string apiMethodName, List<int> adsIdList)
{
    BaseOfApiBridge.UrlMaker($"{dbTableName}/{apiMethodName}/{adsIdList}");

    string result = await BaseOfApiBridge.HttpClientBridge.GetStringAsync(BaseOfApiBridge.Url);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntity>(result);
}
```

Comment: What is the expected format that the server wants?

Comment: Server side is List<int>

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. What format does the server side expect the list to be in for the URL? Is it a query string it expects, or is it a request body?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cheesebaron

I realized that the Method of sending my request was wrong at all. I had to do it by Post Request and send the List<> as a content through the Request Body